# Android Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, grid

I've been looking into the Google Maps API for Android and have followed the example to the letter, however I get the infamous grid without any actual map. I have generated the certificate fingerprint from the debug.keystore, which looks like C2:CD:EC etc.

The certificate given to me from this fingerprint is 0iaQ1NSWtSaR3wy1tAi7GSIVJLJZxQuHt****** where the last six characters are asterisks.

I am able to get overlays to display, its only the map that doesn't load.

UPDATE:
I just downloaded someone else's code and inserted my own certificate and the same thing happens... So there is something wrong with my certificate.

Comment: does the logcat say anything about the emulator not being able to connect to the google server?

Comment: LogCat does not say anything like that

Comment: Is there any place I could download the example program code to be completely sure its not a certificate issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the internet permission in your AndroidManifest file?

make sure this permission is in your manifest. 
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Answer (score 0):

Do you add googlePlayServises? If you test app on emulator, you must run it on emulator which consist GoogleAPi. I can not leave comment, becouse i have not 50 reputation